# What's the difference between HttpResponseMessage and HttpWebResponse?

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse

They both seem to be different ways of handling responses to the client.

More detail about my problem: I have a server in which when I receive a request from a client I want to call a second server and return the response from that second server to my client.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They both serve the same purpose.

- `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse` are available since the first version of .NET, and are still a perfectly valid approach.
- `HttpClient` (which uses `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` to represent requests and responses) has been introduced in .NET 4.5, and offers a fully asynchronous API, along with a new model for request and response content; internally, it still relies on `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`.

An important difference is that `HttpWebRequest/Response` represent the request and response from a client point of view only, whereas `HttpRequestMessage/HttpResponseMessage` can be use by either a client or a server (ASP.NET Web API uses these types to communicate with the client).

You can use the one you're most comfortable with; just be aware that since `HttpClient` is asynchronous, the code that uses it must be asynchronous as well.

Comment: How do you know HttpRequestMessage relies on HttpWebRequest internally ? I do not see any inheritance or common object in class definition : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: @Elo, you don't need to inherit from a class to rely on it... Anyway, I said that HttpClient (not HttpRequestMessage) relies on HttpWebRequest. That's not exactly true, though; HttpClient uses an HttpClientHandler, which itself uses HttpWebRequest. It's not mentioned explicitly in the documentation, but you can see it if you look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpResponseMessage` represent a moden way to use Http. It is being used by REST solutions such as Web API to manipulate status code and the Location header.

`HttpWebResponse` is goold old class that contains all the Http information but considers Obsolete.

Comment: Considered obsolete? By who? The class isn't marked as obsolete, and HttpClient relies on it anyway...

Comment: Hi Thomas, I guess that is my bad. Seems that the constructors are Obsolete  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx