# Httpwebresponse to Httpresponsemessage in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

How can I Convert `httpwebresponse` to `httpresponsemessage` in c#?

```
***var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(queryUri);
            request.Method = "GET";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();***
```

I want to convert this response to `Httpresponsemessage` type.

Or is there any way to get the response from `HttpWebResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this StackoverFlow subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445731/whats-the-difference-between-httpresponsemessage-and-httpwebresponse), I think this is not possible.
HttpResponseMessage is newer than HttpWebResponse (Framework 4.5).

The [HttpResponseMessage class definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and the [HttpWebResponse class definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do not show any common inheritance, and the way to get content is not compatible : content is a [HttpContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) type in the first case, and a stream in the second (see [Microsoft sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So you'll probably have to handle both response types, except if you can migrate your code to use only a single one.